# How to create a "hollow" glass tube

Tags: modeling, shaders, glass

I am working on a cathode ray tube (CRT) based off of an original model. Is there a way to make a glass object (the tube) hollow? In reality, the tube is not filled with glass, so the glass shader default does not yield a good result. I have tried extruding the faces of the mesh a tiny bit inwards, but the result is that the mesh is distorted on the inside. I also tried duplicating the mesh, and scaling it down a tiny bit, but then I have to set the IOR of the shader to something really low, like 1.05. Is there a node setup, or just some kind of way to model your object so that you can render it like a thin glass tube? I would need to see the inner glass, though, like on here. 
[image]
[image]
My render.

Comment: Solidify modifier??  Also CRT tubes were quite thick on the front and acted quite like a lens.

Comment: Yep That sort of worked, but not very well. I'll just use that then. I'm making the first model. Not the ones in TVs

Comment: What do you mean "sort of worked, but not very well"? Solidify is the exact solution for this problem, how much better can it get?

Comment: I was hoping that I would be able to see some of the inner glass, but this works well enough. Thank you!

Comment: Can you describe, why your are not seeing the "inner" of the glass and how would see it in real life photography? Images demonstrating the difference would help.

Comment: There. I added a couple reference photos.

Comment: If you want glass to behave closer to the real world, you need thickness on the geometry. A common mistake is to make the outer shape only. By doing so the glass becomes like a solid mass of glass instead of a thin surface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps something like this is closer to what you're looking for?

[image: CRT Render]

I think this is pretty close to what you've used, but feel free to check out what I've done here.

Transmission = 1

IOR = 1.05

Roughness = 0.167

[image]

Comment: Thank you this helps. Also is there a way to make only the inside reflective? This would be very helpful.

Comment: Actually, adding a little bit of metallic shading fixes pretty much all of my shading problem. Thanks!

Comment: No problem and happy holidays!

Answer (score 3):

Use Cycles render with the Principled BSDF Shader with the following settings:

Roughness: 0

Transmission: 1

This will yield results show in attached.[image: Glass Cup]

Comment: This just gives me the same look as the glass shader.

Comment: Ahh, it looks nothing like the render you submitted.  Considering you 'fixed it' by adding metallic shading, I'm guessing you wanted to see both the inner and outer surfaces.  If I remember correctly, the glass for CRTs did have a very thin metallic film/powder on them.